# Removing the redundancy in Python's 'print' with introspection

Tags: python, introspection

Often I find myself doing something like this when debugging:

```
print a.foo, b.bar, c.baz
```

It prints something like

```
1 3 4
```

which is correct but not as useful as it could be.
What I ideally **want** to be printed is something like:

```
a.foo: 1, b.bar: 3, c.baz: 4
```

which is easily accomplished via

```
print 'a.foo:', a.foo, 'b.bar:', b.bar, 'c.baz:', c.baz
```

but now I'm writing the same thing twice!

Can I use some kind of Python trick like introspection to avoid repeating myself?
I'm imagining a magical `printexp` like this:

```
printexp('a.foo', 'b.bar', 'c.baz')
```

but I'm not familiar with Python's introspection capabilities so I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself:

```
>>> def printexp(*exps, **kwargs):
    import sys
    import inspect
    import itertools
    locs = dict(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals)
    locs.setdefault('_file', kwargs['file'] if 'file' in kwargs else sys.stdout)
    exec('print' + ' ' + '>>' + '_file' + ', ' + (', ' + '_file' + '.write(",")' + ' or ').join(map(lambda exp: '"' + exp.replace('"', '\\"') + ':' + '"' + ', ' + exp, exps)) + '', None, locs)

>>> x = 5
>>> printexp('x', 'x')
x: 5, x: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but if you want to do this with "ordinary" objects (by which I mean objects of user-defined classes), you may want to simply do this:

```
print a.__dict__
```